# Foreach not showing more than one variable

Tags: php, xml, foreach

Currently I have the following code but for some reason it is only outputting one item

Basically What I have tried to do is say foreach `mainPropertyUrl` create a listing foreach listing but for some reason I am only getting back one `ListingId`

The main feed is located - http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Member/4389666/Listings/All.xml

**PHP:**

```
 $mainXmlUrl = simplexml_load_file("http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Member/4389666/Listings/All.xml");

 $listing = $mainXmlUrl->List->Listing;

 $mainPropertyUrl = simplexml_load_file("http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Listings/$listing->ListingId.xml");
```

In my HTML I have tried to do a general foreach loop but not using the `$url` variable as I am unsure how I would implement it with the code that worked for one listing.

I have also tried to create an array of the listing ids but its not showing the data:

```
$ListingArray = array();

            foreach ($listing[0] as $id) {

                $IDNum = $id->ListingId;

                $ListingArray[] = $IDNum;
            }

            var_dump($ListingArray);
```

**HTML Snippit:**

```
<?php foreach ($mainPropertyUrl as $url): ?>

<div class="listingContainer">
<h2><?php echo $tradeMePropertyAddressFull;?></h2>
<div class="listingAttributes">
<div class="col0">
<span class="name"><?php echo $mainPropertyDetails[0]->Attribute[0]->DisplayName;?>:</span>
<span class="value"><?php echo $tradeMePropertyBathrooms[0];?></span>
```

Comment: http://pinterest.com/pin/343118065329946155/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$mainPropertyUrl = simplexml_load_file("http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Listings/{$listing->ListingId}.xml");
```

You need to put `{}` around object access syntax.

UPDATE:

`$listing` is an array, so your loop should be:

```
foreach($listing as $l) {
    $ListingArray[] = "$l->ListingId";
}
```

Comment: It worked fine for one listing when there were none others listed is there a reason behind the {} never seen it before

Comment: I was wrong, I think the braces are only needed when you're calling a method, not accessing a property.

Comment: Any ideas why I cannot get all details?

Comment: Will write another question in 5

Answer (score 0):

Your $mainXmlUrl contains a list of several listings in a brief format. For each of those listings, you will need to call $mainPropertyUrl with a new ListingId to get the detail for that specific listing.

You can loop through $mainXmlUrl->List->Listing, and on each of those nodes, you will be able to retrieve the ListingId as a property.

```
$mainXmlUrl = simplexml_load_file("http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Member/4389666/Listings/All.xml");

$listingIds = array();

foreach ($mainXmlUrl->List->Listing as $listing) {
    // $listing->ListingId is actually an XML object that has a __toString method.
    // Hence the type casting below.
    $listingIds[] = (string) $listing->ListingId;
}

print_r($listingIds);
```

To retrieve detailed information about each listing, you will need to call the mainPropertyUrl on each listing id.

```
$mainXmlUrl = simplexml_load_file("http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Member/4389666/Listings/All.xml");

foreach ($mainXmlUrl->List->Listing as $listing) {
    $mainPropertyUrl = simplexml_load_file("http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Listings/{$listing->ListingId}.xml");

    // $mainPropertyUrl is an XML object containing the detailed information on one listing
    print_r($mainPropertyUrl);
}
```

This will result in a separate API call for each property, so look out for API rate limiting if TradeMe limits the number of requests you can make in a given period.

There may be a way to retrieve multiple listing details in one hit, which would be much more efficient than hitting the API once for the list of products, then again for every listing in that result. You would need to consult their docs though as I'm not familiar with this API.

```
$mainXmlUrl = simplexml_load_file("http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Member/4389666/Listings/All.xml");

foreach ($mainXmlUrl->List->Listing as $listing) {
    $mainPropertyUrl = simplexml_load_file("http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Listings/{$listing->ListingId}.xml");

    echo '<div class="listingContainer">';
    foreach ($mainPropertyUrl->Attributes->Attribute as $attribute) {
        echo '<span class="name">'.$attribute->DisplayName.':</span>';
        echo '<span class="value">'.$attribute->Value.'</span>';
    }
}
```